# Not getting code assist with const variable with Intellij

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, constants, var, code-assist

When I put a variable in const, I simply don't get much code assist from IntelliJ with nodejs plugin. But if I change it to var, I instantly get it. 
As a newbie nodejs player, the course I take, he uses const almost always, and in his Visual Studio IDE, he gets code assist just fine.

The question about it is not precise, as I don't know if he is using const wrong, and IntelliJ is being smart about hiding methods in code assist, or if it's the other way around.

And yes, I've made sure IntelliJ is set up as it should, using Node.js core as library in files, and packages are listed under 'Languages & Frameworks -> Node.js and NPM'. Even installed WebStorm just to check, was just sheer luck I stumbled upon changing const to var, don't remember how I thought about that after a weeks struggle.

EDIT: Attached pictures as requested:

[When code assist works with lowercase letters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fHA0.png)

[When code assist is not showing up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZ2Eg.png)

Comment: Could you please show an example with/without code assistance? What IDE version do you use?

Comment: I found the mistake. If the variable name starts with an uppercase letter, const Validation, then this is where I am not getting code assist. If it lowercase it assists me even if it is a const variable. 
Is this intended behavior?

Comment: Please provide screenshots showing "I simply don't get much code assist" and indicate your IDE version.

Comment: @Oksana ok added two pictures. 
Version used: IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.3 (ultimate edition)
Build #IU-191.7479.19  on May 28 2019